# Why does looking-at ignore the *?

Tags: regular-expressions

I seem to have some misunderstanding with `looking-at`. This is my test
function :

```
(defun lkat ()
  "interactive looking at"
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-at "^\\s-*")
      (message "yes")
    (message "no")))
```

I would expect that it answers with "yes", if point is on any
whitespace after line-start. If I put my cursor at the first space of
a line, this works, but if I put it on the second space, it fails. Is
looking-at not greedy?

Thanks to anyone who points me to my mistake...

Comment: Ok, I see: since looking-at starts its matching at the cursor, it can't match ^ if it is not on the first character. (doh) !

Comment: Also, you should also remove the `*`, as it means "zero or more times", but you want "exactly one time".